# quartz.net 2.0 job do not execute parallel

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

We have 3 quartz.net (version 2.3.3) job configured via xml file

IInterruptableJob Job1Class is marked with DisallowConcurrentExecution and being used by both Job1 & Job2 (of course with different job data) in xml file.

IInterruptableJob Job3Class is used by Job3 in xml file.

quartz.threadPool.threadCount is set to 6 via config file.

Out of 3 job, 2 job is long running and we require that all 3 job should execute in parallel but many time we observed that it do not execute parallel. So why it is not executing in parallel.

Below is the sample xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" version="2.0">
  <schedule>
    <job>
      <name>Job1</name>
      <group>JobGroup</group>
      <job-type>Some.Job1.Class, Some.Job1.Class.Assembly</job-type>
      <durable>false</durable>
      <recover>false</recover>
      <job-data-map>
        <entry><key>keys</key><value>values</value></entry>
      </job-data-map>
    </job>
    <trigger>
      <simple>
        <name>Job1Trigger1</name>
        <group>Triggers</group>
        <job-name>Job1</job-name>
        <job-group>JobGroup</job-group>
        <start-time-seconds-in-future>1</start-time-seconds-in-future>
        <repeat-count>0</repeat-count>
        <repeat-interval>1</repeat-interval>
      </simple>
    </trigger>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>Job1Trigger2</name>
        <group>Triggers</group>
        <job-name>Job1</job-name>
        <job-group>JobGroup</job-group>
        <cron-expression>0 0/1 * * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
    <job>
      <name>Job2</name>
      <group>JobGroup</group>
      <job-type>Some.Job1.Class, Some.Job1.Class.Assembly</job-type>
      <durable>false</durable>
      <recover>false</recover>
      <job-data-map>
        <entry><key>keys</key><value>values</value></entry>
      </job-data-map>
    </job>
    <trigger>
      <simple>
        <name>Job2Trigger1</name>
        <group>Triggers</group>
        <job-name>Job2</job-name>
        <job-group>JobGroup</job-group>
        <start-time-seconds-in-future>1</start-time-seconds-in-future>
        <repeat-count>1</repeat-count>
        <repeat-interval>1</repeat-interval>
      </simple>
    </trigger>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>Job2Trigger2</name>
        <group>Triggers</group>
        <job-name>Job2</job-name>
        <job-group>JobGroup</job-group>
        <cron-expression>0 0 2 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
    <job>
      <name>Job3</name>
      <group>JobGroup</group>
      <job-type>Some.Job3.Class, Some.Job3.Class.Assembly</job-type>
      <durable>false</durable>
      <recover>false</recover>
      <job-data-map>
        <entry><key>keys</key><value>values</value></entry>
      </job-data-map>
    </job>
    <trigger>
      <simple>
        <name>Job3Trigger1</name>
        <group>Triggers</group>
        <job-name>Job3</job-name>
        <job-group>JobGroup</job-group>
        <start-time-seconds-in-future>1</start-time-seconds-in-future>
        <repeat-count>1</repeat-count>
        <repeat-interval>1</repeat-interval>
      </simple>
    </trigger>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>Job3Trigger2</name>
        <group>Triggers</group>
        <job-name>Job3</job-name>
        <job-group>JobGroup</job-group>
        <cron-expression>0/30 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Job1` and `Job2` can't run parallel, because you told Quartz that `Job1Class` has the `DisallowConcurrentExecution` attribute. This attribute works on classes, not on objects. Quartz won't run more than one instance of Job1Class. To fix this behavior, remove the `DisallowConcurrentExecution` attribute from your Job1Class and create 2 subclasses from `Job1Class`. One for Job1 and one for Job2. Then give each new class the attribute and it should work like you want.